# Open a native app with a web fallback

Tags: javascript, native

We're trying to launch our native apps when the user visits a certain URL.

Our apps has registered for a custom URL schema so that part is done.
The problem is to implement the fallback.

What I want is something like this:

```
try {
  # Redirect to the app
} catch(e) {
  # Redirect to the web version
}
```

Which obviously doesn't work since `window.location` doesn't raise an exception.

I tried doing this:

```
window.location = 'some-schema://some/url';
setTimeout(function() { window.location = '/some/url'; }, 100);
```

It does open the app when the user visits the URL. However, when the user returns to the browser the fallback code is executed and the user sees the web version.

This is only one downside. The next time the user visits the URL the app doesn't open (only tested on android) for some unknown reason. Since we don't use 301-redirects I don't see why it would cache the redirect.

I've almost given up and will most likely implement a view saying "click here if you have the app otherwise click here".

Before you ask I cannot open the app from the web version because it's written purely in JS and `window.location` interrupts ajax request and image loading.

Comment: shouldn't the website open anyway if the app isn't installed because there is no url schema registered?

Comment: It should, but ideally it shouldn't open if the app is installed.